# How to scrape all texts from <a href> to List with net.ruippeixotog.scalascraper

Tags: scala, web-scraping

This is the html:

```
<tr class="countries" valign="top"> 
 <td nowrap> </td>
 <td nowrap>
  <a href="https://ar.indeed.com/"><img src="/images/flags/ar.png"></a> 
  <a href="https://ar.indeed.com/">Argentina</a> <br> 
  <a href="https://au.indeed.com/"><img src="/images/flags/au.png"></a> 
  <a href="https://au.indeed.com/">Australia</a> <br> 
  <a href="https://at.indeed.com/"><img src="/images/flags/at.png"></a> 
  <a href="https://at.indeed.com/">Austria</a> <br> 
 </td> 
</tr>
```

I want to get list of text elements between `<a href ...>` and `</a>`. When I write:

```
items >> allText("a")
```

then I get a List of 1 element:

```
ArgentinaAustraliaAustria
```

How to get those texts as n element List?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `texts` method as follows:

```
(items >> texts("a")).filter(_.nonEmpty)
```

Which produces:

```
List(Argentina, Australia, Austria)
```

Filtering is used for the cases like

```
<a href="https://at.indeed.com/"><img src="/images/flags/at.png"></a>
```

since they have an empty text in `<a>` tag